# HttpPost Method in MVC4 does not return the correct View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, return, http-post

In one of my views, the Index View of the Scoring controller, I display some images and make them clickable using javascript. When the images have been clicked I populate an array. Once the user clicks the submit button, the array gets passed over as a string to the Score method in the Scoring controller. In that method, I'm able to set all the data up, and it LOOKS like the new "score" view is getting rendered when I look in the Networks tab using the Chrome debugger...but when I look at the actual browser nothing new is being displayed. I still see the same list of images as before. Why isn't my View getting rendered properly?

Scoring/Index.cshtml js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("img").click(function () {
            // Add and remove border for image
            if ($(this).hasClass('selectedCard')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selectedCard');

                for (var i = 0, len = cardIdList.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (cardIdList[i] === $(this).attr('id')) {
                        cardIdList.splice(i, 1);
                        alert(cardIdList.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).addClass('selectedCard');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                cardIdList = ( typeof cardIdList != 'undefined' && cardIdList instanceof Array ) ? cardIdList : [];
                cardIdList.push(id);
                alert(cardIdList.toString());
            }

        });

        $(".button").on('click', function () {
            $.post("@Url.Action("Score", "Scoring")", { CardIds: cardIdList.toString()});
        });

    });

});
```

ScoringController

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cards = cardDB.Cards.ToList();
        return View(cards);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Score(string CardIds)
    {
        // splits up CardIds string into List
        List<string> cardIdList = new List<string>();
        cardIdList.AddRange(CardIds.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
        CardDeck deckToScore = new CardDeck();
        List<Card> cardsToAdd = new List<Card>();

        for (int i = 0, len = cardIdList.Count(); i < len; i++)
        {
            var card = cardDB.Cards.Find(Convert.ToInt32(cardIdList[i]));
            cardsToAdd.Add(card);
        }
        deckToScore.Deck = cardsToAdd;
        return View(deckToScore);
    }
}
```

Score.cshtml

```
@model GoStopPrimer.Models.CardDeck
```

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Score";
}

```
@for (int i = 0, len = @Model.Deck.Count; i < len; i++)
{
    <img alt= @Model.Deck[i].Name, src= @Model.Deck[i].CardArtUrl id= @Model.Deck[i].CardId />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an AJAX request with `$.post` but not doing anything with the response. Perhaps you intended to provide a `success` callback to your `$.post` call (or call the `.done()` method passing it the callback)?

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: It turns out I was returning the "view" to the post method...and you're right, I wasn't doing anything with it. I had just expected it to render the view...but I ended up displaying it in a div on the previous view instead. Thank you!!